# Plotting data using Gnuplot

Tags: csv, gnuplot

I have a csv file includes two column

```
no. of packet   size 
1               60 
2               70 
3              400
4              700
.
.
.
1000000         60
```

where the first column is

> the number of packet

, and the second column is

> the size of packet in bytes.

the total number of packets in the csv file is one million. I need to plot histogram for this data file by:

```
xrange = [0, 5 , 10 , 15 ]
```

which denotes the packet size in bytes. The range [0] denotes the packet size less than 100 bytes, and [5] denotes the packet bytes less than 500 bytes and so on.

```
yrange = [ 10, 100, 10000, 100000000],
```

which denots the number of packets

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't quite remember exactly how this works, but the commands given in my Gnuplot in Action book for creating a histogram are

```
bin(x,s) = s*int(x/s)
plot "data-file" using (bin(1,0.1)):(1./(0.1*300)) smooth frequency with boxes
```

I believe `smooth frequency` is the command that's important to you, and you need to figure out what the `using` argument should be (possibly with a different function used).

Comment: Brad Richardson... Thank you, i have download this book and i will read the code

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
# binning function for arbitrary ranges, change as needed
bin(x) = x<100 ? 0 : x<500 ? 5 : x<2500 ? 10 : 15 

# every occurence is counted as (1)
plot datafile using (bin($2)):(1) smooth freq with boxes
```

Im not really sure what you mean by "yrange [10 100 1000 ...]", do you want a logscaled ordinate?

Then just

```
set xrange [1:1e6]
set logscale y
```

before plotting.

Comment: Karl Ratzsch... The [y] values in the output graph denote the number of packet from 1 to one million

Comment: Karl Ratzsch... when i implemented you code above, i got this message error invalid expression for the line code                                                              bin(x) = x<100 ? 0 : x<500 ? 5 : x<2500 ? 10 : 15

Comment: can't be, i just pasted it into the gnuplot console and it worked as expected. Check "help ternary operator" to see how the function works.

Comment: Karl Ratzsch... Thank you for your help .

Comment: You're welcome. Btw., if you ask a gnuplot question, you should stick to the gnuplot syntax. Your range specifiers e.g. are very obscure.